# a while loop inside a for loop not working in codeigniter view file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

so I have a codeigniter view file that has a code inside like this:

```
  <?php for($i=1; $i <= count($headings); ): ?>
      <div class="row">
      <?php while(($i%3) != 0 ): ?>
          <div class="span4">
          <?php $heading = current($headings); ?>       
              <h2><?= key($headings); ?></h2>
              <p><?= $heading['description']; ?></p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="<?= $heading['link']; ?>">View details &raquo;</a></p>  
              <?php next($headings); ?>
              <?php $i++; ?>
           </div> <!-- end of div.span4 -->
           <?php endwhile; ?>
       </div> <!-- end of div.row -->
   <?php endfor; ?>
```

What I want to achieve here is to loop through the array `($headings)` by three's. I want to produce something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
    <div class="span4"><!-- $heading element --></div>
</div>\
```

at the above example the `$heading` array contains 8 elements, so it produce 2 `div`'s with a class of row, inside is 3 `div`'s with a class of `span4`. With the third div of class row only containing 2 `div`'s of class `span4`.

Now, when I try to run this on the web server, it returns an empty page, no HTML tags whatsoever or PHP error. And i'm pretty sure that my php `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`. Tried to remove it and the page loads fine (of course without div's that the code in question should create).

i resolve this problem by using a different logic. see below

```
<?php for($i=1; $i <= count($headings); ): ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php for($k=1; $k <= 3; $k++): ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <?php $heading = current($headings); ?>
        <?php if ($heading !== false): ?>
            <h2><?= key($headings); ?></h2>
            <p><?= $heading['description']; ?></p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="<?= $heading['link']; ?>">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php next($headings); ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    </div> <!-- end of div.span4 -->
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div> <!-- end of div.row -->
<?php endfor; ?>
```

but still i'm wondering as to why the code in question doesn't work when logically it should be fine.

Am I missing something or does codeIgniter prevents nested loop of such way. Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance for the answers!.

Comment: you don't need nested loops, just an if to check if `i%3 == 0` then close the row and start a new one

Comment: check you server error log and make sure the display_errors configuration directive is set to On... You are probably getting an error when you call next($headings) on the last row.

Comment: @koala_dev, i dont know if it's just the common cold i have right now messing with my brain or i just can't see having an if `$i%3 == 0` inside my for loop do the job. Can you please provide the bare code/pseudo code of what's in your mind? thanks alot!.

Comment: @Orangepill, i checked my error_log file, there seems to be no abnormalies there, such as fatal error, but i do find this in my php_error_log: _PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133169152 bytes) in /opt/lampp_1.8.2/htdocs/my-codeigniter-starter-kit/application/views/welcome/welcome_message.php on line 18_ does this mean i'm having an infinite loop here, or it's just taking long? thanks.

Comment: @Mischa, I've already done research on that, it and seems its ok to leave the iteration on the for loop blank since i'm doing the iteration of the variable `$i` inside my while loop. as proof, it works fine on my solution code (see the last code block on my post) Thanks.

Comment: how big is your array?

Comment: @Orangepill, when i was trying this, only three. I already saw my mistake, seems like i'm having an infinite loop inside my `while` . anyway thanks for your advise, i will now regularly check the error_log when i encounter bizarre results. thanks again!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with just a check of the element index

```
<div class="row">
<?php for($i=0; $i < count($headings); ): ?>
    <?if($i > 0 && $i%3 == 0):?>
        </div><!-- end of div.row -->
        <div class="row">
    <?endif?>
    <div class="span4">
    <?php $heading = current($headings); ?>       
        <h2><?= key($headings); ?></h2>
        <p><?= $heading['description']; ?></p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="<?= $heading['link']; ?>">View details &raquo;</a></p>  
        <?php next($headings); ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    </div> <!-- end of div.span4 -->
<?php endfor; ?>
</div><!-- end of div.row -->
```

**EDIT** I just realized you have string indexes, so I updated to use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`

**EDIT 2**

The reason your first code is not returning anything is because you fall in an infinite loop when you break from the while the first time, that is when  $i == 3, see in your next `for` iteration the while condition is not met and since your $i++ is inside the while the value of $i is now forever stuck at 3

Comment: hahaha! i see my fault now, your entirely correct, i do run into an infinite loop, when i included an iteration on my `for` loop `for($i=1;  $i < count($headings); $i++)` it got out of the infinite loop, but it only shows in two's and not in three's. well i'll be erasing that anyway and use your code since its much much better. Thanks!.